# Insert datetime in SQL without millisecond using a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, datetime

I need to insert a .net DateTime in my SQL Server DataBase without the milliseconds.

```
dtNow = Date.Now
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MyDate", dtNow)
```

I want the values on my database to be, for example: `2014-01-15 17:18:04.000`
Being the seconds the more accurate value.

But it adds the actual milliseconds when I make an insert like this one:

```sql
INSERT Table1 (MyDate, id, MyValue, DateModified) 
VALUES (@ADate, @ID, @Value, @MyDate)
```

How can I achieve this in the simplest way?

Comment: Do `dtNow.AddMilliseconds(-(dtNow.Millisecond))` before inserting into the DB.

Comment: @user2989408: you'd need to use the result of the call - just calling `Add` won't change `dtNow` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *could* subtract the number of milliseconds as suggested in comments, that would still leave you with submillisecond values. That *may* not cause a problem, but it's possible that the driver will round the submillisecond value up to a whole millisecond. It's cleaner (IMO) to avoid having any subsecond value at all, so that the value you insert is the same as the value which gets stored. I'd prefer to use:

```
var truncated = new DateTime(dtNow.Year, dtNow.Month, dtNow.Day,
                             dtNow.Hour, dtNow.Minute, dtNow.Second);
// Use truncated as the parameter in your command
```

That way it will clearly *only* have year/month/day/hour/minute/second values.

If you find yourself doing this regularly, you might want to write an extension method so that you can use:

```
var truncated = dtNow.TruncateToSecond();
```

Comment: I was afraid some answer like this. I was hoping where was a simpler way.

Comment: Hmmm of course it works but isn't SQL Server datetime granularity higher than one millisecond (0, 3, 7 msec?)

Comment: @SysDragon: One extension method which you then call whenever you need to - that seems pretty simple to me... and if you're usually using "now", you can write a method to return "the current time truncated to the nearest millisecond".

Comment: Ideally, yes, but unfortunately at work we use Framework 2.0 which doesn't not have extension methods. And they don't want to change at all.

Comment: @Adriano: I don't see why that's relevant. The OP wants a granularity of "1 second" and this code gives that.

Comment: @SysDragon: So you just use a static method instead of an extension method - it's really not a big deal. And you *can* use extension methods with .NET 2.0 if you declare the right attribute and use a C# 3+ compiler.

Comment: @JonSkeet just to say that if he still has submilliseconds or not it's not a problem in this specific case!

Comment: @Adriano: Oh, I see - well it depends on what the driver does. Suppose the original value is 15:12:34.9999999. After removing the milliseconds, that would be 15:12:34.0009999... which the driver might round up to 15:12:34.001. It's surely cleaner to insert a value which doesn't have *anything* subsecond.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm I guess you're right, I just assumed it converts to FILETIME then ignoring LSBs. Oh, this makes me think another thing: Kind property is lost in this conversion!

Comment: @Adriano: Yes, `Kind` is generally a problem (as it's not part of the datetime model in SQL Server)... but then `DateTime` is broken to start with, IMO. I was trying to focus on the immediate problem of removing the subsecond information.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I just remember I had some problem for interop (DateTime <-> FILETIME in native code) because of that but honestly I can't remember in which scenario it doesn't work as expected. Anyway I guess it's not OP's problem...